# Question about irreducible topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is an irreducible topological space, and that $Y$ and $Z$ are closed irreducible subsets of $X$.  If $\dim Y=\dim Z$, and $Z \subseteq Y$, does this imply that $Z=Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw something just like this. Basically if $\dim Y$ is finite, then $Z = Y$, because if not then any chain $Z_0 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq Z_n = Z$ can be made longer by adding $Y$ to the end. But if $\dim Y$ is infinite then I don't think this is true anymore.

Comment: You're welcome!